# Javascript: How am I misusing the regexp constructor here?

Tags: javascript, regex, constructor

```
_("test1: "+ ("slayers get more".match(RegExp("^" + "slayers get magic"), "g")));
```

I am expecting the result "slayers get m" but instead I get null?

Typing a regexp literal instead does work.

Another question: How do I get it to match whole words only, so that the result would be "slayers get" ?

thx

Comment: The new keyword is missing `new RegExp`

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help.  I actually had the 'new' keyword and removed it to see if it would improve anything.  Inserting it does not create the expected behaviour...

Comment: `match(new RegExp("^" + "slayers get magic", "g"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `"g"` should be the second argument to `RegExp()`, not the second argument to `.match()`. (Though with your regex starting with a `^` to match from the beginning of the string you don't need `"g"` at all.)

In addition it would be "more correct" to use `new` as follows:

```
_("test1: "+ ("slayers get more".match(RegExp("^" + "slayers get magic", "g"))));
```

However I believe in the case of `RegExp()` it works with or without `new`.

> *'I am expecting the result "slayers get m" but instead I get null?'*

`null` is the correct result for that string and that regex, because it *doesn't match*. That is, a regex is either going to match or not (in this case not), it doesn't return the portion of the string that made a partial match.

It seems like what you really want to do is return that part of the first string that matches the beginning of the second string, up to but not including the first different character. If so, try this:

```
function getCommon(s1,s2) {
   var i = 0, len = s1.length;
   while (i < len && s1.charAt(i) === s2.charAt(i))
      i++;
   return s1.substr(0,i);
}

_("test1: "+ getCommon("slayers get more", "slayers get magic"));
```

> *'Another question: How do I get it to match whole words only, so that the result would be "slayers get"?'*

Building on the same idea as my previous function, just compare one word at a time:

```
function getCommon(s1,s2) {
   var a1 = s1.split(" "),
       a2 = s2.split(" "),
       len = a1.length,
       i = 0;
   while (i < len && a1[i] === a2[i])
      i++;
   return a1.slice(0,i).join(" ");
}
```

This splits both strings up into individual words, compares one word at a time until there is a mismatch, and returns the words that matched up until that point (or an empty string if none matched).

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/j8zsU/1/

Comment: Thanks.  I was hunting for a way to not have to do it by hand, though, which I thought was the point of stuff like regexp.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

1. [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) only takes one argument but you're passing it two. I think you want to pass the `"g"` to the `RegExp` constructor: `new RegExp("^" + "slayers get magic", "g")`
2. The `"slayers get more"` string does not match the `/^slayers get magic/` regex so of course `match` returns `null`.

If you do:

```
"slayers get more".match(new RegExp("^" + "slayers get m"))
```

then you'll get the result that you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a misunderstanding of how regex operators work. What your regex "^slayers get magic" is saying is look for the phrase "slayers get magic" at the beginning of a string. This means that unless the beginning of your string is an exact match, it will return null. What you need to do is make every word optional, that way it can drop the words which don't match. (I'm not a regex expert, I'd really suggest reading through [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), it's a great regex resource)

```
"slayers get more".match(RegExp("^(slayers)? (get)? (magic)?", "g"))
```

This code adds the optional operate (?) around each word so that the match will match what is available. This returns:

```
["slayers get "]
```

Instead of null.

Comment: This isn't useful to me because the string in question isn't known by the programmer.  I reduced it to string literals while troubleshooting but that's not what the live code will be using.

Comment: @abeisgreat - Wouldn't your regex also match on `"slayers  magic"`? Or just `"  magic"`.